# Convert Json to Array, extracting only values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an JSON file:

```
['0': XXX, '1': YYYY]
```

I would like to extract this into an array with only the value via jquery.

```
['XXX', 'YYYY']
```

What is the best way to do this?

.makeArray doesn't seem to work.

Comment: shouldn't the json be {'0': XXX, '1': YYYY}

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
var data = {
  '0': 'XXX',
  '1': 'YYYY'
};

var valuesOnly = Object.values(data);

console.log(valuesOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do this by

```
var obj = {'0': XXX, '1': YYYY};
var arr = $.map(obj, function(el) { return el });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `JSON.parse` this way:

```
function parsing(jsonStr){

     return JSON.parse(jsonStr);
 }
var jsonStr = "['0': XXX, '1': YYYY]";
var arr = parsing(jsonStr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain JavaScript instead of using jQuery:

```
var json = {'0': "XXX", '1': "YYYY"}
Object.values(json) // ["XXX", "YYYY"]
```